# Remove default apps from Django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

By default, in Django-admin there is Users, Groups, and Sites apps. How can I remove Groups and Sites?

I tried to remove `admin.autodiscover()` from root urls. Then, when I added something like `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` somewhere in my app models I got an `AlreadyRegistered` exception (this is fairly right - models users already registered in django.contrib.auth).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In an admin.py you know will definitely be loaded, try:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.unregister(Site)
```

Comment: You will need to import them (or I did):

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

Comment: This method that will not work if you load your apps before the django apps. I have to do this to ensure my apps' custom registration templates overwrite the default django registration templates in 3.2. This will result in `NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)` errors if the app with the admin.py is loaded before the django apps. @user2745509's solution below works regardless of INSTALLED_APPS order, but is much less clean.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the above double check your ordering of "INSTALLED_APPS" in "settings.py"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django apps first
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # custom apps below
    'my_app'
]
```

Otherwise it will cause an error. See here: [Issue with Django admin registering an inline user profile admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729866/issue-with-django-admin-registering-an-inline-user-profile-admin)

Comment: Yes, this helps. Your app must be below other ones. Otherwise, the user model is still from the original app(contrib.auth), not yours.

Answer (score 8):

To get rid of Users and Groups I had to do in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Need to import this since auth models get registered on import.
import django.contrib.auth.admin
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.contrib import auth

admin.site.unregister(auth.models.User)
admin.site.unregister(auth.models.Group)
```

Comment: This is the only method that will work if you, like me, load your local apps before your django apps. I have to do this to ensure my local app's custom registration templates overwrite the default django registration templates in 3.2. The accepted answer will result in `NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)` errors if your app is loaded before the django apps.

Answer (score 4):

Loop through all apps, and unregister any models they have registered.

```
from django.apps import apps


# De-register all models from other apps
for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
    for model in app_config.get_models():
        if admin.site.is_registered(model):
            admin.site.unregister(model)


# Register only those models you want
...
```

Comment: This is a best answer. Not sure where to add it, because in AppConfig.ready it is to late. I have added this on the top of the admin.py in my 1st app registered in INSTALLED_APPS. Additionaly I have added condition to let Users untouched, something like: `if not app_config.name == 'django.contrib.auth' # before the model loop`

Answer (score 2):

If you got:

> django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model Group is not
>   registered

Then make sure that your INSTALLED_APPS in proper order like this:

```
enter code hereINSTALLED_APPS = (
# [1] Django apps
'django.contrib.auth',
...

# [2] your custom apps
'anyproject.anytuff',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_models():
    if model.__name__ and admin.site.is_registered(model):
        admin.site.unregister(model)
```

this will unregister all models depending upon the position of app where this code is placed and it's order inside INSTALLED_APPS so make sure the apps you want in your admin are placed after the app in which this code resides.

[image]

For Example: if this code is placed inside users app, it will unregister all models before users and all models after users can be registered.