# cannot remove installed apps from admin

Tags: django, django-admin

this is a followup question to [Remove default apps from Django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342031/remove-default-apps-from-django-admin)

I am trying t remove Sites from my admin site and I call

`admin.site.unregister(Site)`

as was suggested.

Iam getting an error saying that Site is not registered. Apparently my admin.py is called before the Site model is registered. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish what I need?

thanks
konstantin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cause was a wrong ordering of installed applications. here is the answer: [Issue with Django admin registering an inline user profile admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729866/issue-with-django-admin-registering-an-inline-user-profile-admin)