# How to hide model default in Django admin?

Tags: django

When I started project, Django provided for me an app has default tables, such as Email addresses, Email confirmations in ACCOUNTS. But I don't want those appear in my admin page. How can I hide it in admin page?

Comment: Are you looking to remove the Users, Groups, and/or the Sites models from the admin? That's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342031/remove-default-apps-from-django-admin

Comment: I have visited to link your share... so import models from where??

Comment: from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, User (or *)