# How do I remove the "Account" section from the Django Admin Page

Tags: django

I would like to remove the "Account" section from the Django Admin page.

I can't figure out what model I would need to unregister().

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove default apps from Django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342031/remove-default-apps-from-django-admin)

Comment: No. I'm trying to remove the account section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using a third party application [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts).

To disable this feature, add this into your `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import (
 Account,
 AccountDeletion,
 EmailAddress,
 PasswordExpiry,
 PasswordHistory,
)

admin.site.unregister(Account)
admin.site.unregister(AccountDeletion)
admin.site.unregister(EmailAddress)
admin.site.unregister(PasswordExpiry)
admin.site.unregister(PasswordHistory)
```

If you do not needs this application, remove it from your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "account",
    # ...
)
```